# After 20 years, do we now understand more why the nobel prize discovery blue LED GaN works?

Tags: solid-state-physics, crystals, light-emitting-diodes

From the book The Blue Laser Diode: The Complete Story, it said that

> Indeed, maybe one of the most puzzling
> and amazing facts about present gallium nitride-based devices is why they
> work so well at all, given the huge numbers of defects in them!

I am wondering, after 20 years, is this problem still puzzling for scientists? How far have we understood about this problem?